# Should 90° S, 180° W and 90.0°S, 180° E produce different C-Squares

Tags: python

I created a simple C-Squares encoder in Python as a training exercise to help me understand how the encoding system works.

From my understanding limited understanding of geosystems and reading the spec; 
    90° S, 180° W and 90.0°S, 180° E are both the same spot on the earth and yet the C-Squares are '5817:499' and '3817:499' respectively.

Is this correct?

https://github.com/zeonglow/csquares

Answer (score 3):

I just came across your post, apologies for the delayed response. I am Tony Rees, formerly of CSIRO (independent since 2014), and I wrote the original c-squares specification back in 2002, revised 2005 (http://www.cmar.csiro.au/csquares/spec1-1.htm).

The question you pose is a good one. In the c-squares spec I addressed it as follows:
9.4 Exceptions
Exceptions to this rule are as follows:

- Bounding cases of latitude (+90, -90) are encoded within the next "lower" square, i.e. ten degree square +80 to +90, or -80 to -90 (since no "higher" squares exist)
- Bounding cases of longitude (+180, -180) are encoded within the next "lower" square, i.e. ten degree square +170 to +180, or -170 to -180 (since no "higher" squares exist)

As you discovered, this means that a point at notional longitude "-180" or "+180" will indeed be encoded differently, although they represent the same point on the ground. This can be viewed as a deficiency in the c-squares specification, which could (as in the case of zero, which is declared to be positive for encoding purposes), also declare that -180 longitude should be treated as +180 (or vice versa). I will run it by a few other persons to see if this is an acceptable solution and then add it to the list of "exceptions" in the spec (e.g., convert any values of -180 to +180 before further processing); the same steps will then need to be added to the various online or offline converters that the been provided, and source code for the same. Thanks for spotting this. Regards - Tony Rees (c-squares originator), Tony.Rees@marinespecies.org

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% familiar with C-Squares, although reviewing the literature it seems like a really nice concept.

Your question relates to how the script reads the East and West definition of the line of Longitude.

So if you say that the coordinate is 90S and 180W...then the coordinate would read -90 ; -180 and if you refer to the coordinate as 90S and 180E the would read -90 ; 180.

I would guess that the grid cannot work with values exactly at these boundaries, to avoid this type of confusion. So I think (and I will explain why I think this now), the script you are running reads the 180 degree and the 90 degree as 179.9 and 89.9.

The first value of the C-Square reference refers to the Global Sector in which your point lies. So that is NE, SE, SW, NW. A value of 1 is NE, 3 is SE, 5 is SW and 7 is NW.

Your references are 5817 (South West Grid) and 3817 (South East Grid).
The second value in the reference refers to the "tens of degrees south/north", which should be 9 if 90 was being used, in your case it is 8, meaning its using 80.
The last two number in the reference is "tens of degrees west/east". If it were reading 180 this should be 18, but it is 17 in your case.

The last three digits in the reference handle the position of the point in a 5 degree quandrant and the use of the additional degrees (remainders from the 10s used in the first 4 numbers).

In your case the last three digits are 499

4 - fourth quandrant
9 - that is 9 degrees south
9 - that is 9 degrees east / west

Taking this all into account, the coordinates used to generate your C-Square Reference are therefore

89 Degrees South
179 Degrees East
-179 Degrees West

I hope that make sense.
I got this from presentation on the CSIRO Website.
http://www.cmar.csiro.au/csquares/csquares1.ppt

http://www.cmar.csiro.au/csquares/resources.html#presentations

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply;  I was attempting to replicate what the example Perl script does on the CISRO website,  the spec says to go up a square when 'on the line' except for 90 and 180 where you go back.  I might edit my implementation to just reject extreme co-ordinates. if the eggheads at CISRO couldn't think of a pure solution, I'm pretty sure I'd struggle!

Comment: Cool glad you came right...I think the example of 90 and 180 are rare cases...an option would be to choose one way to deal with it and stick with it...to remain constant...

Answer (score 1):

OK, thinking about this a little more, values of -180 and +180 longitude are indeed the same on the ground (as are any conceivable value of longitude combined with -90 latitude, and the same for +90 longitude) there is some value in maintaining them as conceptually separate in the case where such a coordinate pair represents the terminal point of a series, or a line.

Let us look at the case of a set of points approaching but not crossing the dateline, from west to east, with longitude of (e.g.) +179, +179.5, +180. Then in this case it is probably preferable to represent all these points within the same longitudinal hemisphere, i.e. consider +180 to be the eastern limiting point or square. However approaching from the opposite direction, with a series e.g. -179, -179.5, -180 it makes more sense for the dateline to be considered the westernmost limit. Therefore, maintaining 2 different codes for the representation of +180 vs. -180 (for the same latitude) would have some value in these situations.

Regards - Tony Rees